# how to write the Radau 2nd order methods (Butcher’s table)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I would like to solve the Robertson problem [you can find the system here](https://www.radford.edu/~thompson/vodef90web/problems/demosnodislin/Single/DemoRobertson/demorobertson.pdf)
this is a stiff system of ODE which require an implicit high (more than one) order solver. In particular the RADAU IIA was used as reported in several paper. 
I would like to understand and know the final form of RADAU IIA method 2 order 
about it I have the Butcher's table which is :

```
1/3  |  5/12  -1/12
1    |  3/4    1/4
_____|_______________
     |  3/4    1/4
```

you can find reference about Radau and the butcher's table [here](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/IRK.pdf) 
may some one explain me how to derive the radau method ? and how the table works ?
may somebody help me ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y'(t) = f(t,y(t))$, $y(t_0)=y_0$ be your initial value problem. Set $u_0 = y_0$. Then the $i+1$-th iteration of a runge-kutta method with $s$ stages is defined as

$$
u_{i+1} = u_i + h \sum_{j=1}^{s} b_j \cdot f(t_i+c_j \cdot h,\, u^{(j)}_{i+1}) \\
u^{(j)}_{i+1} = u_i + h \sum_{k=1}^{s} a_{jk} \cdot f(t_i + c_k \cdot h,\, u^{(k)}_{i+1})
$$

where

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
c_1 & a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1s}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c_s & a_{s1} & \cdots & a_{ss} \\ \hline
& b_1 & \cdots & b_s
\end{array}
$$

is the given butcher tableau.

The butcher tableau for the second order RADAU IIa method (which is a [l-stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-stability) runge-kutta method) yields:

$$
u_{i+1} = u_i + h  \cdot \left( \tfrac34 \cdot  f(t_i+\tfrac13 h,\, u^{(1)}_{i+1}) + \tfrac14 \cdot  f(t_i+h,\, u^{(2)}_{i+1}) \right)
$$
with
$$
u^{(1)}_{i+1} = u_i + h \cdot \left( \tfrac{5}{12} \cdot f(t_i + \tfrac13 h,\, u^{(1)}_{i+1}) - \tfrac{1}{12} \cdot f(t_i + h,\, u^{(2)}_{i+1})  \right) \\
u^{(2)}_{i+1} = u_i + h \cdot \left( \tfrac{3}{4} \cdot f(t_i + \tfrac13 h,\, u^{(1)}_{i+1}) + \tfrac{1}{4} \cdot f(t_i + h,\, u^{(2)}_{i+1})  \right)
$$

Because Radau IIa is a implicite method, you have to solve the nonlinear equation system defined by the last two lines for $u^{(1)}_{i+1}$ and $u^{(2)}_{i+1}$ in each iteration.

Comment: thank you very much !!!!

Comment: sure I'm sorry !! but I forgot to doing before because I'm enjoy writing new solver thank to your answer!

Comment: do yu know also the equations for the 4th order Radau methods ?

Comment: I'm try to figure out the table and then I give you the link of new topic :)

Comment: No problem! [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Radau_methods) you can find the butcher tableau for the 4th order Radau IIA method.

Comment: oh thank you !! have a look ! :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883510/how-to-get-the-radau-5th-order-equations-give-the-butcher-tableau