# How do I derive the fifth-order Radau II method in the form of a Butcher Tableau

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to derive the fifth-order Radau II method in the form of a Butcher Tableau, by finding the individual values for $c_i, b_i$ and $a_{ij}$?

So far I have $20t^3 - 36t^2 + 18t - 2 = 0$,
and for its roots I got $1.0000, 0.6449$ and $0.1551$ (to 4 decimal places).

How do I calculate the values of $b_i$ and $a_{ij}$?

I understand that you need to fulfil the conditions of $B(k)$ and $C(k)$, but in this situation, what number is $k$ going to be?

Comment: I've added some math formatting to give you an idea of what you can do to express [mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  There's a good bit you could (should) add to your Question to better explain what you know and what explanation is really needed from your Readers.

Comment: Check out this closely related Question:  [How to get the Radau 5th order equations give the Butcher tableau](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883510/how-to-get-the-radau-5th-order-equations-give-the-butcher-tableau)